# Copy previous cell format, data and font if two conditions are met

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I know I'm doing this wrong, I can't quite figure out the nomenclature for VBA. Basically, I want to copy the format, data and font from the cell above a cell if two conditions are met. To be exact, I want Z8 to copy format, data and font from Z7 if and only if Z8 is empty and S8 has information in it. Otherwise Z8 stays that way. And I want to do it for a specific range.

I would prefer not to use SET since I want to use other macros and I don't want range to be permanently set.

```
Sub ZFillTest()
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim rng As Range

i = 0
k = 0
i = i + 4
k = k + 4

rng = ("Z5:Z200")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Offset(k, 8).Value <> "" And cell(k, Z + i).Value = "" Then
    cell(k, Z + i).Value = cell(k, Z + i - 1).Value

    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is required to instantiate an object. You need to create a `Range` object and loop through it, to do that you *have* to use `Set`. That's not to say you can't set it to something different at a later stage.

Have a try with the code below:

```
Sub ZFillTest()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Z5:Z200")
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = vbNullString And r.Offset(0, -7).Value <> vbNullString Then
            r.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Destination:=r
            r.Value = r.Value 'if you don't want formulas copied over
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked absolutely fantastic, you guys are so incredibly fast and informative.

Comment: @strictlybananas, no problem at all - we're happy to help! If that resolved your question please accept the answer (the grey tick mark on the left). If you found the answer useful and you're feeling kind please also upvote (the up arrow, also to the left)

Comment: I did upvote! But I don't have much reputation so it doesn't display. I'll Accept your answer, thanks again!

Comment: It's not copying the information correctly unfortunately

Comment: It appears to not be copying from r.Offset(-1, 0) but some weird amalgamation of cells around it. Not in all cases, just in some.

Comment: Could you update your question to include a screenshot of your data - and example of what you expect to happen? I'm sure we can resolve this

Comment: Sure, I'll do it after lunch

Comment: I updated. I included a script I ran before that works the way I want it to but it prevents me from running another macro appropriately for some reason. I also included a screenshot of what happens when I run your script. The bold cells are the ones that I want to be copied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137790/discussion-between-callumda-and-strictlybananas).

Comment: Oh! Nevermind, I got it. I ended up using just copy and then paste specials instead of copy and destination. I did as follows: